# How can I change the localSID for a SAMBA Server?

Tags: samba, samba4

I am trying to change the localSID for a SAMBA server, however I am unable to. I have tried the command "net setlocalsid" to no avail. To troubleshoot I have also stopped the smbd and nmbd services, but this did not help. Any help would be great!

```
root@TheWiggle:~# net getlocalsid
SID for domain THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# net getdomainsid
SID for local machine THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000
SID for domain THISDOMAIN is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# net setlocalsid S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net getlocalsid
SID for domain THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# net getdomainsid
SID for local machine THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000
SID for domain THISDOMAIN is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# net setdomainsid S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net getdomainsid
SID for local machine THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000
SID for domain THISDOMAIN is: S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net setlocalsid S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net getlocalsid
SID for domain THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# service smbd stop && service nmbd stop
smbd stop/waiting
nmbd stop/waiting

root@TheWiggle:~# net setlocalsid S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net getlocalsid
SID for domain THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000

root@TheWiggle:~# net setdomainsid S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111

root@TheWiggle:~# net getdomainsid
SID for local machine THEWIGGLE is: S-1-5-21-748580849-194208185-3916830000
SID for domain THISDOMAIN is: S-1-5-21-33300351-1172445578-3061011111
```

Comment: Not sure if it's gonna help, but *smbd* and *nmbd* daemons are not the only ones in Samba ver. 4. They only serve files and the remainder of domain services in implemented in *samba* daemon. It likely contains *samba* string in the service name.

Comment: which version of samba?

Comment: I'm using Samba version 4.

Comment: Maybe you also need to delete `secrets.tdb`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the sid once I put the server in a backup domain controller mode. Since this server does not need to be an actual domain controller this mode was fine.

```
server role = classic backup domain controller
```

Hopefully this helps anyone with this issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and before changing the netlocalsid of the HOST, I had to change the sambaSID of the sambaDomainName=HOST in the LDAP.
After you changed the sambaSID with the value you want to change, the command # net setlocalsid 
works well.